# Сводная таблица openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

Как в openpyxl создать сводную таблицу excel?
Файл для примера тут https://yadi.sk/i/topX92JAJ6N4gQ

Answer (score 1):

В данный момент библиотека openpyxl не поддерживает создание сводных таблиц. Есть возможность только редактировать существующие.

> openpyxl provides read-support for pivot tables ...

Перевод:

> openpyxl обеспечивает поддержку чтения для сводной таблицы ...

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pivot.html